# Puzzle identification and solving algorithm

Tags: algorithms, puzzle, problem-solving

I am trying to solve 8x8 puzzle (total 64 buttons). Similar to LightsOut, but in this rules are different. Goal is turn ON every button.

Example:

```
Button 1 is turned on/off by buttons 25, 36
Button 2 is turned on/off by buttons 25, 55
Button 3 is turned on/off by buttons 20, 58
...
Button 20 is turned on/off by buttons 4, 9
...
Button 25 is turned on/off by buttons 22, 59
...
Button 36 is turned on/off by buttons 42, 50
...
Button 55 is turned on/off by buttons 3, 24
...
Button 64 is turned on/off by buttons 29, 32
```

Full list is available here: http://pastebin.com/9b0MKXCb

I see that every button can be turned ON/OFF by any of 2 buttons (it's always 2).

I succeeded solving it manually by trial & error method, but I would like to do it proper. Program starts with all lights (buttons) turned OFF. Target is to turn ON all of them.

Is this still LightOuts problem? How can I solve it?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

I've been asked why is this 8x8 puzzle. I called it that because there is total 64 buttons. Is this wrong?

For example. If I wish to turn ON button 1, I have to click on button 25 or 36. If I click two times on 25 or 36 state is restored - it's like nothing happened.

So if I wish to turn ON buttons 1 and 2 I have to click on button 25 OR button 36 AND button 55.

Comment: Is the only move by the player to choose two buttons and push them simultaneously? Otherwise you can push all the buttons and win in one move. What is 8x8 in this puzzle? Can you tell us anything else? A puzzle of this kind need not have a solution.

Comment: Samuel, thanks for feedback. I've edited my post. Please ask if you need more information. Also, solution exists, I've been told by author and I managed to solve it with try-error method.

Comment: How are the buttons numbered?  what does 25, 36, etc. mean?

Comment: vadim123, I cleaned up the question, please check above. 25 means button number 25.

Comment: Clicking on 25 turns button 2 on, but shouldn't then clicking on button 55 turn button 2 off again?

Comment: You may need to be much more explicit with how a numbered light is connected to the two numbered buttons that power it. Your first two lights use (25, 36) and (25, 55). If your third light used (36, 55) these three lights form an odd cycle that would _prevent_ a solution. I know your third light is not using these buttons, but if there is an odd cycle somewhere else, there would be no solution. So I'm afraid that you need to give a fomrulaic pattern for how light $N$ relates to buttons $(f(N),g(N))$; either that or list everything out.

Comment: Ok, I listed everything out that I have. Please take a look at the different perspective - state and relationship. I've commented first couple of lines in both. Here is complete list: http://pastebin.com/9b0MKXCb

Comment: Samuel, yes, if I click on button 25 I turn ON button 2 and if I click on button 55 I will turn OFF button 2. That's why I have to choice only one trigger button.

Comment: Then what you wrote in your post is wrong: you will not turn on buttons 1 and 2 by clicking buttons 25 and 55.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that last line in UPDATE was wrong. I corrected it now. It should be: So if I wish to turn ON buttons 1 and 2 I have to click on button 25 OR button 36 AND button 55.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_i$ be the number of times you push button $i$. You'll only ever push it $0$ times or $1$ time, so be can take $x_i$ to be modulo $2$.

You would like light 1 to go from OFF to ON. When we examine the chart in the link in your comments, we can only affect light 1 by switching buttons 25 or 36. This yields an equation: $$x_{25}+x_{36}\equiv1$$ so that light 1 will be left ON. Repeat this for every light, and you have 64 equations modulo $2$ in $64$ variables modulo $2$. This system of equations can be solved through row reduction of the corresponding matrix (or possibly row reduction will reveal there is no solution.) If there is a solution, it is either

- a specific set of values of 0s and 1s for the $\{x_i\}$,
- or it is a larger solution set that maybe parametrized, from which you can find an optimal specific solution my minimizing (the integer value of) $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{64}$.

---

Let's take a smaller, $2\times2$ example. Mimicking the link you provide:

1 = [2,4] (button 1 triggers state change on button 2 AND button 4)
2 = [1, 3] (button 2 triggers state change on button 1 AND button 3)
3 = [1, 2, 4] (button 3 triggers state change on button 1, button 2, AND button 3)
4 = [3]

$$\begin{align}
\text{To turn on light 1} &&x_2+x_3&=1\\ 
\text{To turn on light 2} &&x_1+x_3&=1\\ 
\text{To turn on light 3} &&x_2+x_4&=1\\ 
\text{To turn on light 4} &&x_1+x_3&=1\\ 
\end{align}
$$

This system of equations has matrix 
$$\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1&0&1\\
1&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&0&1&1\\
1&0&1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$
Row reducing (if you do not know how to do this, please research it online - wikipedia should do) yields:
$$\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&1&1\\
0&1&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

$x_4$ is a free variable, so we can use a parameter $t$ for $x_4$. $t$ can range between $0$ and $1$. For the rest, we read (using modulo 2 arithmetic) $x_1=1-t, x_2=1-t, x_3=t$. This yields two solutions. $t=0\implies(1,1,0,0)$ and $t=1\implies(0,0,1,1)$.

So we could either push buttons 1 and 2, or buttons 3 and 4. the order that we push them in is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks alex.jordan! Can you please give me little bit more instructions for next step thru example? It's been a long time since I've done any math :(

Comment: alex.jordan, btw, what do you think that I'll ever push some button 0 or 1 time?

Comment: Also, how could I determine in which order I should press buttons?

Comment: @noob I added a $2\times2$ example. Also, you should understand that order is irrelevant. Whether we push button A, then button B or vice versa, the net effect is the same.

Comment: Ok. I wrote 64 equations with your instructions and converted it into matrix and run row reduction echelon form on them. Here is the defined matrix and row reduction echelon form result for this set: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3wMFbBca. Please save as txt file and open in notepad so it doesn't break correct newlines. How can I proceed?

Comment: thank you for explanation. Btw, are you sure that above example is correct? I've run it thru SciLab application (similar to mathlab) and here are the results: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Ez4viJTk

Comment: Ignore - solved it! Thank you very much!